# how to append a string value to existing column value in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method in my ruby model like the following:

```
def testing
  update_stock = Stock::Detail.find(stock) # (Assume I have a stock id.)
  update_stock.update_attributes(details: "dashboard")
end
```

The above is working fine. But If the `details` has a value already like `'table,chair'` as a `string`. How can I append the `'dashboard'` to the `details` field. Currently the `update_attributes` remove the old value and update the new value. I want to append the value to existing value.

### Update Question:

If I declare the string value into the variable like

```
detail_value = 'Code: 123AB, dashboard, code: 1235Q, table, chair'

def testing
  update_stock = Stock::Detail.find(stock) # (Assume I have a stock id.)
  update_stock.update_attributes(details: detail_value)
end
```

I want to append the `details` column where the above `code` is not exists already.

### Update for Max comments

For example, my details column has a value like

```
'Code: 123AB, dashboard, code: 1235Q, table, chair'   # Before
```

and my parameter is `'Code:123AB, dashboard'  # Parameter`

I want to remove the `parameter` from the `string` value and update to the database column.

So my `column` value would be `'code: 1235Q, table, chair'`

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused - the question was about appending (adding) a string to the existing value, but in your example, the parameter string is **removed** from the existing value.

Comment: Hi Max, I got adding part and removing part and done the add part. Thanks

Comment: It's bad Stack Overflow behaviour to ask one question and then when it's answered, say, "Oh and there was something else..."

Comment: However, i will update my answer :)

Comment: Ok Thanks Max. I will make sure not to repeat this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not like this:

```
def testing
  update_stock = Stock::Detail.find(stock)
  update_stock.details += 'dashboard'
  update_stock.save
end
```

Update answer: maybe check if this string occurs in `details`:

```
update_stock.details += 'dashboard' unless update_stock.details =~ /dashboard/
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you Marek. One more question is If the value is existing I dont want to append. I just want to append the new values.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Marek's answer, you could add a "setter" method which appends the string rather than replaces it.  Then you can just do the standard update_attributes in your controller: personally i think it's good to keep the controller actions as standardised as possible.  eg

```
# in Stock::Detail

#setter method
def append_details=(s)
  self.details ||= ""
  unless self.details.include?(s)
    self.details << " #{s}"
  end
end

#getter version of above - just shows the value of details
def append_details
  self.details || ""
end
```

Now in your view, you can say, eg

```
<%= form_for @detail do |f| %>
    <label>Details <%= f.input :append_details %>
    ...
```

Now you can just do the standard behaviour in your create controller, eg

```
@detail.update_attributes(params[:detail])
```

Couple of notes:

1) Personally i think you're asking for trouble having a model called Detail which has a method .details - this is confusing.

2) Have a look at `serialize` - it might be better to save this as an array of strings, rather than a string.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

EDIT - similar method to remove a substring from the field.

```
# in Stock::Detail

#setter method
def subtract_details=(s)
  self.details ||= ""
  self.details = self.details.gsub(s,"").gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip
end

#getter version of above - just shows the value of details
def subtract_details
  self.details || ""
end
```

The `.gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip` bit just tidies up the string, converting multiple spaces to single spaces, and getting rid of leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks Max. In this case, `detail_value = 'Code: 123AB, dashboard, code: 1235Q, table, chair'` I want to remove the string value from `Code: 123AB, dashboard`. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but i don't understand quite what you mean.  Can you list the "before" string, the parameter string and the "after" string?

Comment: Hi Max, I update my question. Can you please have a look. Thanks